# On Android version 2.3.5 and version 2.3.6 my back button is not displaying properly

Tags: css

And the screen shot on android aap is this - http://screencast.com/t/jvO2nn1zMlN8

Copied CSS from http://cssnerd.com/2011/11/30/the-best-pure-css3-ios-style-arrow-back-button/